# Why are these path segments misaligned?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, winui-3

I'm trying to create a circle constructed of several arcs using several [XAML Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.shapes.path?view=winrt-22621) objects (declared in code). The problem is that upon drawing them, the paths end up misaligned, as shown in the picture below (attempting to draw two 180 degree arcs).

[image]

It gets progressively worse the more paths are added, which suggests the misalignment somehow accumulates.

[image]

I've rechecked my math several times. I also tried offsetting the x-value by 1 position in case the error was from overlapping path segments. Perhaps it is a deeper issue with rendering?

### Code

The code is a little rugged, but in a nutshell, I'm starting from `Angle = 0`, adding 45 degrees, drawing an arc up to that point, and repeating the process again from where the previous arc ended. Just as shown in the second picture.

```
double Angle = 0;
double Radius = 150; //half the width of the yellow square
Point StartPoint = new Point(150, 0);
...

Arcs = new ObservableCollection<Path>(); //used as a source for ItemsControl to bind to

while (Angle < Math.PI*2)
{
    Angle += Math.PI / 4;

    //subtracting Math.PI/2 to account for starting the first arc at x=150, y=0
    double sin = Math.Sin(Angle - Math.PI / 2); 
    double cos = Math.Cos(Angle - Math.PI / 2);

    double nX = Math.Round(cos * Radius + 150);
    double nY = Math.Round(sin * Radius + 150);
    Point endPoint = new Point(nX, nY);

    Path p = CreatePath(StartPoint, endPoint);

    StartPoint = endPoint;
    Arcs.Add(p);
}
```

The `CreatePath` function is mainly XAML filler, but here it is just in case

```
private Path CreatePath(Point start, Point end)
{
    PathSegment ps = new ArcSegment()
    {
        Size = new Size(Radius, Radius),
        Point = end,
        SweepDirection = SweepDirection.Clockwise
    };

    PathFigure pf = new()
    {
        StartPoint = start,
        IsClosed = false,
        IsFilled = false,
        Segments = new PathSegmentCollection() { ps }
    };

    Geometry g = new PathGeometry()
    {
        Figures = new PathFigureCollection() { pf }
    };

    Path p = new()
    {
        Data = g,
        Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
        StrokeThickness = 3
    };

    return p;
}
```

P.S. Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that upon creating several Path objects, each of them pushed its neighbors, thus resulting in a slight, but accumulative misalignment. I presume there are two solutions:

1. Refactor the code into keeping everything within one parent Path object. I didn't opt for that because I'd like to use distinct [Property animations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/motion/xaml-property-animations) on each Path segment.
2. The more hacky solution I went for. Upon creating each Path object, add an extra property,

```
Path p = new()
{
    Data = g,
    Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
    StrokeThickness = 3,
    Margin = new Thickness(-1) //<--- somehow corrects for the misalignment
};
```